# テーブルタグでのjavascriptを使用したcellのTextBoxのnameやidの取得

Tags: javascript, html5

HTMLやjavascript使用しテーブルタグで表を作ろうと思っています。
その際、cellはTextBoxとし、

```
<input type="text" name="a" id="id_a" value="" size="1" maxlength="1" />
```

のようにcell内はなっているものとします。TextBoxに数値等を入力しそのTextBoxの値を取得しjavascriptでtableの要素を順に取得して数値を出力したいと考えておりました。
TextBoxの値を取得する場合、nameやidが不明だとTextBox内の値を取得できないと思うのですが、このような場合どのようにnameやidをjavascriptで取得することができますでしょうか
当初は以下のように考えておりました。

```
function acquisitionRow(obj) {
    // テーブル取得
var table = document.getElementById(id);

    // td内のtrをループ。rowsコレクションで,行位置取得。
    for (var i=0, rowLen=table.rows.length; i<rowLen; i++) {
    // tr内のtdをループ。cellsコレクションで行内セル位置取得
    for (var j=0, colLen=table.rows[i].cells.length ; j<colLen; j++) {
       //i行目のj列目のセルを取得
       var cells = table.rows[i].cells[j];
       //取得したセルのidを取得
       var cell_id = cells.document.querySelectorAll

　　　　//取得した値を書き出す
```

このようにcellの位置を取得してidの値を取り出してというような考えだったのですがこのようやり方自身正解かどうかも分からず、より良い方法はあっ‌​たりしますでしょうか。
宜しく願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`document.getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/document/getElementsByTagName)や[`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)などを用いることで`<input>`要素を抽出することができます。
後はどのような条件で抽出を行うかですが、この点は質問文に記載されていないため答えようがありません。

Comment: すいません、ありがとうございます。
全くの素人でいろいろと質問に不備があり申し訳ありません。
tableの要素を順に取得して数値を出力したいと考えておりました。

`        // テーブル取得
 var table = document.getElementById(id);
 
        // td内のtrをループ。rowsコレクションで,行位置取得。
        for (var i=0, rowLen=table.rows.length; i<rowLen; i++) {
  // tr内のtdをループ。cellsコレクションで行内セル位置取得
  for (var j=0, colLen=table.rows[i].cells.length ; j<colLen; j++) {
     //i行目のj列目のセルを取得
     var cells = table.rows[i].cells[j];
     //取得したセルのidを取得

                   //取得した値を書き出す
`
のようにcellの位置を取得してidの値を取り出してというような考えだったのですがこのようやり方自身もっと良い方法はあったりしますでしょうか。

Comment: @x001017 コメントされるのではなく、質問文を更新して頂けませんか？

Comment: @sayuriすいません、更新するべきでした。